# Advanced custom fields in WP - images

Tags: php, wordpress, field

I can't get ACF's to show images.

I created a field with the field type of image-1

```
<img src="<?php the_field('image-1'); ?>" alt="" />
```

All it shows is the broken image thing in chrome. 
Is anyone familiar with this plugin and knows how to get image fields to work?

Comment: Is it field of `type image` and `name image-1` ? Is the image being shown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you meant the field type is 'image', not 'image-1'.  Your code is completely correct.  More likely you are having other unrelated issues.  I would guess that you might be having some sort of permissions issue, and the image is not actually being uploaded.

First, check the javascript console.  In Chrome, right-click (ctrl-click on mac) the image, select 'inspect element' to open Chrome Dev Tools, and see what the img src is.  In Dev Tools, right click on the img src and select 'open in new tab'.  That should open up the image directly.  My hunch is that the image won't open this way.  If that is the case, then the image was not correctly uploaded by ACF, and the error has nothing to do with the PHP code you are using to display it (which as I've said is completely correct).

There are various permissions related issues that you would need to look into.  Here's a link to one such issue: http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/discussion/3395/image-upload-bug/p1.

UPDATE:

Based on your comment regarding getting thumbnails to work, here's the code you would need:

```
$attachment_id = get_field('image-1');
$size = "thumbnail"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
// url = $image[0];
// width = $image[1];
// height = $image[2];
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
<?php
```

Comment: I got it working, I was being an idiot and setting it to return the image ID instead of the image URL in the settings.

The problem I face now is getting the image to show as a thumbnail, which I cannot seem to get to work!